# getting ghostscript in docker image for mac

Tags: macos, docker, ghostscript

Apologies if this is a trivial question, I am very new to docker.

I'm trying to install ghostscript in a python base running on a mac. I've looked online and seen people load gs on linux with apt-get and on windows loading an exe installer program. On mac Ghostscript is loaded using brew, but brew is not in my docker image.

What options do I have? Should I try to find and pull a layer ghostscript? Copy the lib files into my image in the dockerfile? Somehow get brew in my image and use that to load?

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why the closed votes? I know this is a relatively simple question, but I am home doing this on my own and have not ever used docker. I've been through documentation and done a few tutorials, have searched a lot online, and tried a lot of different things, which the question indicates - I found and said how to do this on linux and windows and explained why those don't work on mac.  I realize the question might not be of general interest, but it has been blocking me for several days.

Comment: You can build Ghostscript from source. You need gcc and GNU make (clang should work also) and it should build easily from source. I've built GS from source on a Mac many times.

Comment: @KenS Thank you, that had not occurred to me. It works! I guess that way makes the image platform independent, where copying the libraries would make it reliant on mac and the right  version. So I learned something about how to use docker.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out well for you.

Answer (score 0):

KenS's answer works - building from source code gives what I need, and also works for other architectures (where things like the apt-get or .exe installer I found through searches are platform dependent). I learned something about using Docker from his answer.